# Elasticsearch: Bulk upsert

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say each of my documents has (at least) two fields: A and B. I want to perform a (bulk) operation which, if a document doesn't exist, will create both A and B fields, but if the document exists, will only overwrite B. I tried to following:

`{"update": {"_id": my_id, "_index": index_name, "retry_on_conflict": 30}}`

`{"doc": {"B": some_val}, "upsert": {"A": another_value}}`

It behaves as follows: if the document already exists, field B is overwritten (that's what I want). But if the document doesn't exist, it's created with only field A. I want it to be created with both A and B.

I cannot completely overwrite the document, since it may also have more fields (other than A and B) which I don't want to touch in this operation. Also, I prefer not to use scripts, as they're slower, and in the past they gave me many errors. I searched the documentation, but found no hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it this way, i.e. by specifying both `A` and `B` in the upsert document.

```
{"update": {"_id": my_id, "_index": index_name, "retry_on_conflict": 30}}
{"doc": {"B": some_val}, "upsert": {"A": another_value, "B": some_val}}
```

Using `doc_as_upsert: true` wouldn't work in your case, since you don't want to overwrite `A` if the document exists.

Comment: Seems it would work. Thanks. But in my real case, A is a pretty huge (struct) field, and there's actually more than one such a field (the in question I only gave the essence). So I was hoping for a more economic solution.

Comment: For the lack of a better answer, I'll accept our answer. It does work, after all.